# Items disapear when `sort!`'ing a list in Guile

Tags: sorting, scheme, guile

I seem to have a case of disappearing items after invoking `sort!` on a list of strings:

(I have derived this code from Autogen template that I was working on.)

```
(use-modules (ice-9 pretty-print))

(let ((files '("log4cplus/socketappender.h"
              "log4cplus/qt4debugappender.h"
              "log4cplus/nteventlogappender.h"
              "log4cplus/ndc.h"
              "log4cplus/msttsappender.h"
              "log4cplus/mdc.h"
              "log4cplus/loglevel.h"
              "log4cplus/loggingmacros.h"
              "log4cplus/logger.h"
              "log4cplus/log4judpappender.h"
              "log4cplus/log4cplus.h"
              "log4cplus/layout.h"
              "log4cplus/hierarchylocker.h"
              "log4cplus/hierarchy.h"
              "log4cplus/fstreams.h"
              "log4cplus/clogger.h"
              "log4cplus/asyncappender.h"
              "log4cplus/version.h"
              "log4cplus/tstring.h"
              "log4cplus/qt5debugappender.h"
              "log4cplus/nullappender.h"
              "log4cplus/fileappender.h"
              "log4cplus/consoleappender.h"
              "log4cplus/clfsappender.h"
              "log4cplus/appender.h"
              "log4cplus/win32debugappender.h"
              "log4cplus/win32consoleappender.h"
              "log4cplus/tracelogger.h"
              "log4cplus/tchar.h"
              "log4cplus/syslogappender.h"
              "log4cplus/initializer.h"
              "log4cplus/configurator.h"
              "log4cplus/config.hxx"
              "log4cplus/thread/threads.h"
              "log4cplus/thread/syncprims.h"
              "log4cplus/thread/syncprims-pub-impl.h"
              "log4cplus/thread/impl/tls.h"
              "log4cplus/thread/impl/threads-impl.h"
              "log4cplus/thread/impl/syncprims-pmsm.h"
              "log4cplus/thread/impl/syncprims-impl.h"
              "log4cplus/thread/impl/syncprims-cxx11.h"
              "log4cplus/spi/rootlogger.h"
              "log4cplus/spi/objectregistry.h"
              "log4cplus/spi/loggingevent.h"
              "log4cplus/spi/loggerimpl.h"
              "log4cplus/spi/loggerfactory.h"
              "log4cplus/spi/filter.h"
              "log4cplus/spi/factory.h"
              "log4cplus/spi/appenderattachable.h"
              "log4cplus/streams.h"
              "log4cplus/internal/socket.h"
              "log4cplus/internal/internal.h"
              "log4cplus/internal/env.h"
              "log4cplus/internal/cygwin-win32.h"
              "log4cplus/helpers/thread-config.h"
              "log4cplus/helpers/socket.h"
              "log4cplus/helpers/pointer.h"
              "log4cplus/helpers/lockfile.h"
              "log4cplus/helpers/connectorthread.h"
              "log4cplus/helpers/timehelper.h"
              "log4cplus/helpers/stringhelper.h"
              "log4cplus/helpers/socketbuffer.h"
              "log4cplus/helpers/snprintf.h"
              "log4cplus/helpers/queue.h"
              "log4cplus/helpers/property.h"
              "log4cplus/helpers/loglog.h"
              "log4cplus/helpers/fileinfo.h"
              "log4cplus/helpers/appenderattachableimpl.h"
              "log4cplus/config/windowsh-inc.h"
              "log4cplus/config/win32.h"
              "log4cplus/config/macosx.h"
              "log4cplus/boost/deviceappender.hxx")))
  (begin
    ;; Add the generated header as it will not be found by file search.
    (append! files (list "log4cplus/config/defines.hxx"))
    (display "before sort:\n")
    (pretty-print files)
    (sort! files string<?)
    (display "after sort:\n")
    (pretty-print files)))
```

The output that I see is this:

```
before sort:
("log4cplus/socketappender.h"
 "log4cplus/qt4debugappender.h"
 "log4cplus/nteventlogappender.h"
 "log4cplus/ndc.h"
 "log4cplus/msttsappender.h"
 "log4cplus/mdc.h"
 "log4cplus/loglevel.h"
 "log4cplus/loggingmacros.h"
 "log4cplus/logger.h"
 "log4cplus/log4judpappender.h"
 "log4cplus/log4cplus.h"
 "log4cplus/layout.h"
 "log4cplus/hierarchylocker.h"
 "log4cplus/hierarchy.h"
 "log4cplus/fstreams.h"
 "log4cplus/clogger.h"
 "log4cplus/asyncappender.h"
 "log4cplus/version.h"
 "log4cplus/tstring.h"
 "log4cplus/qt5debugappender.h"
 "log4cplus/nullappender.h"
 "log4cplus/fileappender.h"
 "log4cplus/consoleappender.h"
 "log4cplus/clfsappender.h"
 "log4cplus/appender.h"
 "log4cplus/win32debugappender.h"
 "log4cplus/win32consoleappender.h"
 "log4cplus/tracelogger.h"
 "log4cplus/tchar.h"
 "log4cplus/syslogappender.h"
 "log4cplus/initializer.h"
 "log4cplus/configurator.h"
 "log4cplus/config.hxx"
 "log4cplus/thread/threads.h"
 "log4cplus/thread/syncprims.h"
 "log4cplus/thread/syncprims-pub-impl.h"
 "log4cplus/thread/impl/tls.h"
 "log4cplus/thread/impl/threads-impl.h"
 "log4cplus/thread/impl/syncprims-pmsm.h"
 "log4cplus/thread/impl/syncprims-impl.h"
 "log4cplus/thread/impl/syncprims-cxx11.h"
 "log4cplus/spi/rootlogger.h"
 "log4cplus/spi/objectregistry.h"
 "log4cplus/spi/loggingevent.h"
 "log4cplus/spi/loggerimpl.h"
 "log4cplus/spi/loggerfactory.h"
 "log4cplus/spi/filter.h"
 "log4cplus/spi/factory.h"
 "log4cplus/spi/appenderattachable.h"
 "log4cplus/streams.h"
 "log4cplus/internal/socket.h"
 "log4cplus/internal/internal.h"
 "log4cplus/internal/env.h"
 "log4cplus/internal/cygwin-win32.h"
 "log4cplus/helpers/thread-config.h"
 "log4cplus/helpers/socket.h"
 "log4cplus/helpers/pointer.h"
 "log4cplus/helpers/lockfile.h"
 "log4cplus/helpers/connectorthread.h"
 "log4cplus/helpers/timehelper.h"
 "log4cplus/helpers/stringhelper.h"
 "log4cplus/helpers/socketbuffer.h"
 "log4cplus/helpers/snprintf.h"
 "log4cplus/helpers/queue.h"
 "log4cplus/helpers/property.h"
 "log4cplus/helpers/loglog.h"
 "log4cplus/helpers/fileinfo.h"
 "log4cplus/helpers/appenderattachableimpl.h"
 "log4cplus/config/windowsh-inc.h"
 "log4cplus/config/win32.h"
 "log4cplus/config/macosx.h"
 "log4cplus/boost/deviceappender.hxx"
 "log4cplus/config/defines.hxx")
after sort:
("log4cplus/qt4debugappender.h"
 "log4cplus/qt5debugappender.h"
 "log4cplus/socketappender.h"
 "log4cplus/spi/appenderattachable.h"
 "log4cplus/spi/factory.h"
 "log4cplus/spi/filter.h"
 "log4cplus/spi/loggerfactory.h"
 "log4cplus/spi/loggerimpl.h"
 "log4cplus/spi/loggingevent.h"
 "log4cplus/spi/objectregistry.h"
 "log4cplus/spi/rootlogger.h"
 "log4cplus/streams.h"
 "log4cplus/syslogappender.h"
 "log4cplus/tchar.h"
 "log4cplus/thread/impl/syncprims-cxx11.h"
 "log4cplus/thread/impl/syncprims-impl.h"
 "log4cplus/thread/impl/syncprims-pmsm.h"
 "log4cplus/thread/impl/threads-impl.h"
 "log4cplus/thread/impl/tls.h"
 "log4cplus/thread/syncprims-pub-impl.h"
 "log4cplus/thread/syncprims.h"
 "log4cplus/thread/threads.h"
 "log4cplus/tracelogger.h"
 "log4cplus/tstring.h"
 "log4cplus/version.h"
 "log4cplus/win32consoleappender.h"
 "log4cplus/win32debugappender.h")
```

As you can see, the after sorting list is missing half of the items.

What am I doing wrong in the Scheme source?

**UPDATE**

So by trial and error I have stumbled upon what seems to be a fix. When I change `(sort! files string-ci<?)` to `(set! files (sort! files string<?))`, I get the desired result. But I am confused, why is in-place sort not working as I expect.

Comment: "why is in-place sort not working as I expect" `sort!` doesn't do in-place sorting.  It *returns* a sorted list.  It's allowed to modify the list structure that you pass in (in any way).

Comment: Also, literal data is to be treated as immutable. The effect of mutating literal data is undefined, and often not what you expect. In your case, instead of using `'("log4cplus/socketappender.h" ...)`, just use `(list "log4cplus/socketappender.h" ...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manual:

> Sort the sequence items, which may be a list or a vector. less is used for comparing the sequence elements. The sorting is destructive, ***that means that the input sequence is modified to produce the sorted result***. This is not a stable sort.

https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Sorting.html

The procedure is destructive however it doesn't promise that input sequence is usable. So you always need to use returned value as a sorted sequence.

Comment: OK. I misunderstood. I thought it would update the binding as well. Thanks!